# C# - Button counter won't increase when clicked more than once

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have the following code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    count1++;
}
```

I want the counter count1 to increase every time someone clicks on the button. However, so far it only counts the first click, and not any other following, so it's always stuck on 1. Outside, I have declared it and set its initial value to 0. Where is the problem? (I use visual studio 2015)

Edit: This is the whole code:

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Statistics : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    int count1 = 0, count2 = 0;
    string minima = "Καλησπέρα";
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            TextBox1.Text = minima;
            Label1.Text = "Αυτή την στιγμή χρησιμοποιούν τον ιστότοπο " + Convert.ToString(Application["UserCount"]) + " χρήστες";

        }

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text;
        count1++;
        Label2.Text = "Κλικ από προηγούμενους χρήστες: " + Convert.ToString(count1);
        Label3.Text = "Τρέχοντα κλικ: " + Convert.ToString(count1 + count2);
    }
}
```

(yes I know count2 is not changing its value at any point, the code is still in progress regarding that, as it is there for another reason so let's ignore it for now)

Comment: The problem is not in this function. Show other code related to counter

Comment: Show us how and where you define it, where you initialize it and what process does the variable go through. When you define an empty int property, the default value is 0, so when you click the first time it goes up by 1. Therefore it means you probably initialize the property wrong.

Comment: You should store the count somewhere, if it is not in ViewState then in Session or a permanent store like a file or a database. The code that you have will run every time your page gets loaded, so it will reset to 0 on each call.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying, as we haven't used ViewState or something like that so far to store variables.
I am very new to this and I've only written beginner code in java before, so please bear with me.

Comment: You need to learn about the [page lifecycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) each click of the button creates a new instance of the class. Fields in the class like counters do not automatically survive and need to be saved then reread on the next page load from in the viewstate or in the session.

Answer (score -1):

Your counters are reseting every postback
try this

```
static int count1,count2;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        TextBox1.Text = minima;
        Label1.Text = "Αυτή την στιγμή χρησιμοποιούν τον ιστότοπο " + Convert.ToString(Application["UserCount"]) + " χρήστες";
        count1 = 0;
        count2 = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have more than one visitor to the website it will not work as you expect it to. Try opening two tabs in your browser and try the program out.